# How to make showEvent() get called?

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

What do I need in order to have `showEvent()` be called in a `QWidget` derived class?

**ConfigMenuForm.h**

```
//simplified the code of the class declaration
class ConfigMenuForm : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit ConfigMenuForm(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~ConfigMenuForm();

signals:

public slots:

private slots:

protected:
    void showEvent(QShowEvent *event) override; //with or without the override keyword, no change
private:
}
```

**ConfigMenuForm.cpp**

```
//amongst others
void ConfigMenuForm::showEvent(QShowEvent * event)
{
    //do some stuff here - really simple
}
```

I can't have it triggered when I `show()` my widget... 
I mean the code has no effect and when placing a break point, it doesn't stop on it, so I assume the event is not triggered.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT - adding some more code and precision:

I'm using QtCreator 3.0.0 with Qt 5.2.0 (MSVC 2010, 32 bit)

```
//creating the widget in the main window's constructor (class Viewer)
// ConfigMenuForm calls hide() in its own constructor
 m_configMenuForm = new ConfigMenuForm(this);
```

then when I press a button on the main window

```
void Viewer::ontBConfigClicked()
{
    m_configMenuForm->show();
}
```

What confuses me is that `m_configMenuForm` is actually shown on top of the main window, it becomes visible and properly works! It's just that the showEvent is not called.

Comment: How are you calling this widget's `show`?

Comment: In order to get `showEvent` called, You just need to do what you *said* you have done. Here is a [minimal example](http://pastebin.com/3FCjuS990). If you are testing by placing a break point, maybe you haven't attached the debugger to your application. if you are using Qt Creator, you need to use the "Start Debugging" button `F5`  (not the "Run" button `ctrl + R`).

Comment: @Jonathan Mee: directly calling the `show()` slot from another widget that's owning this widget

Comment: @Mike: yes thx for the tips, using QtCreator for a few months now @ job, it's precisely what I've been doing. Seeing this weird behaviour I thought I was missing something that I couldn't see because of the reflexes I have now ^^ I'll have a look at the example.
Really seems weird to me, I can debug the closeEvent of the main window but the showEvent still doesn't work. Could it be because of some eventFilter?

Comment: @RDK I want to see the connection. You've put the wrong code in your question. If you're not hitting your `showEvent` method, it's because the connection is in error, so you still have yet to show us the code that's actually the problem.

Comment: Ah Mike, the page is no longer available at the link you provided...  (sry for the comments spam)

Comment: I guess there's nothing anywhere in the documentation that should make you think that this event will be delivered from within the `show()` method - if there is, point to the relevant piece of documentation. That's about it. Of course you should declare your method `override` to ensure you have no typos that would make the method useless. And you should also ensure that the widget really gets shown (you should be able to point it out on the screen with your finger and be certain that it's the same widget that you think it is). And of course the widget must be invisible first.

Comment: @RDK Is your definition of `showEvent` right there in your header as you have it listed there? That shouldn't even compile, at least not without an `inline` on the declaration line.

Comment: Corrected the snippet, now it seems good and understandable

Comment: It seems that there is a problem with my project or something of the sort as I just tested the idea in a small fresh project and it's working like a charm. I'll post the solution when I find out what's wrong. Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm answering my own question as in the end it was not a programming issue.
Something must have gone wrong with the compilation/debug stuff.

For the record, here is what to do if everything is right in your code but for some freakin' reason a function is not called(maybe it can only happen with Qt's event handlers reimplementations?).

This happened using QtCreator 3.0.0 with Qt 5.2.0 MSVC2010 - 32 bits

1. Clean the project: Menu  *Build->Clean All*
2. Close QtCreator
3. Go to your build-project/debug folder and remove the .exe, .pdb and .ilk files
4. Go to your build-project/cache folder and delete the folder with the same name as your project suffixed with .pdb (yourproject.pdb folder) - not sure if this is necessary, but I did it so I write it down here too
5. Restart QtCreator, qmake, build and run/debug (and tadaaa!)

A "simple" clean all didn't do the trick, not even a computer restart. I had to manually delete the files that weren't deleted by QtCreator.

I hope it can help someone in the future, saving a couple of hours.

Comment: This really helped me: two of us had spent a couple of hours trying to get a breakpoint to be hit in some code that uses showEvent(). So this solved the issue for me in Qt 6. Note: I wiped the whole debug directory and built afresh.

Answer (score 2):

To set break point in visual studio refer this : [breakpoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k80ex6de(v=vs.100).aspx)

showEvent() called when you restore window for more info  [showEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#showEvent)

Code Snippet :-

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <iostream>

//Move this class to any header file then exceute
class widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
protected :
    void showEvent( QShowEvent * event )
    {
        QWidget::showEvent(event);
    }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    widget w;
    w.show(); //Here showEvent() get called
    return app.exec();


}
```